# Database design (simple product options)

Tags: sql

I need some input to my database design for my shop. I want to add simple options to some of the products, etc. color.

Products:
ProductID, ProductName

Then I want to add a color (user chose color in dropdown on productcart).

Can somebody help?

Comment: Do you use a relational database (for instance MySQL)? Is this your general Product table, is there a second table for the productcart?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a field name color in the Products table.

For those Products do not have color, just leave it empty string

Answer (score 0):

If you want a drop-down menu, you need to store the available colors for each product in the shop.

One way is to start with a table for all existing colors, let's (not unreasonably...) call it **Colors**. It contains a numerical id and the name for each color: **Colors(Id, Name)**

Then you need a table that stores which products are available in which colors. Each row contains a product id and a color id, which together form a unique key. I also like to add an extra id, which sometimes simplifies programming: **ProductColors(Id, Product, Color)**